# integrando o php com o DB do mongoDB

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, mongodb

Estou fazendo uns teste para salvar as informações do site no banco de dados e o código que escrevi para ver se o `PHP` e o banco estão ligados foi esse:

```
<?php
    $mng = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://login-hpfbn.gcp.mongodb.net:27017");
    $stats = new MongoDB\Driver\Command(["dbstats" => 1]);
    $res = $mng->executeCommand("phpbasic", $stats);
    $stats = current($res->toArray());
    print_r($stats); 
?>
```

e o site esta me mostrando esse erro:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'MongoDB\Driver\Manager' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\phpmongo\test.php:4 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\phpmongo\test.php on line 4

Comment: O próprio erro já te notifica que a classe não foi encontrada. Já viu [essa documentação do PHP relacionada ao MongoDB](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/mongodb.tutorial.library.php)?

Comment: li so o da extensao esse ainda não, vou dar uma olhadinha, muito obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Falta do modulo mongodb no PHP.
Para instalar o modulo do mongodb você vai precisar:

- libbson e libmongoc (https://github.com/mongodb/libbson)

Instalar por PECL:

```
sudo pecl install mongodb
```

No php.ini insira isto:

```
extension=mongodb.so
```